# debug with PHP script on IE10

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a js script that uses ajax to post data to a php script. The php script will open a text file and write the data that's passed from the js script. The same script works on chrome on a different machine but after I migrate it to the server where only IE is available, it does not work.

After executing the POST script in js, my browser shows the `success` message but the data in the text file is not changed. One problem I can think of is the directory I put in my php script is not correct. So I added these lines from w3schools to see if the file is actually found, but nothing peculiar happened:

```
 if(!file_exists("welcome.txt")) {
      die("File not found");
} else {
     $file=fopen("welcome.txt","r");
 }
```

What are some other ways I can do for debugging in this case?

### UPDATE

I think my php in general is not working for some reasons. I have replaced everything in my php file with

```
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello"); </script>';
```

I am assuming when I click the button on my webpage, the js will do a $ajax post and the php script will be executed showing the alert message. However nothing yet shows up

Comment: Are you sure PHP has permission to write to the file? Try temporarily changing it to be writable by all.

Comment: Have you checked that the user your PHP script is running as has permission to write to that file?

Comment: How should I check and change for that?

Comment: Curious why you mention specific browser. If code works in other browsers then problem is with js not php. Simply not enough information given for anyone to troubleshoot without asking 20 questions

Comment: I think your problem is 'I migrated to a new server', and not 'IE10'. Have you enabled the visibility of PHP errors? Make sure you do!

Comment: Yes, the browser is a red herring, it will be server configuration that it causing the issue. Can you please provide more information regarding what OS you are now hosting your PHP on and an idea of how you have configured it?

Comment: @DazzKnowles the server is configured on linux centos using apache

Comment: @KIKOSoftware what is the best way to set it? Do I need to change anything in php.init or is it just a line of code I can add into my php script?

Answer (score 0):

In a PHP script you can turn error reporting on with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Error and warnings will show up that will give you possibly a hint where your script is failing.